# Query para encontrar duplicata por DATETIME (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, select, datetime

Bom dia a todos. Necessito uma ajuda para entender melhor como aplicar uma `query` que estou desenvolvendo.

Precisaria formular um `SELECT` que buscasse determinados registros dentro de um período envolvido `(DATETIME)`.

No DB:

```
# sala_c, date_start, date_end, name
'AUD_BARATA', '2020-01-25 14:00:00', '2020-01-25 15:00:00', 'TESTE AVISO APÓS GRAVAR'
'SAL_EVENTOS', '2020-01-25 15:00:00', '2020-01-25 16:00:00', 'DESCRIÇÃO EVENTO'
'SAL_SALAGRUPO', '2020-01-28 13:00:00', '2020-01-28 14:00:00', 'TESTE GRUPO TESTE'
'SAL_SALAGRUPO', '2020-01-28 13:00:00', '2020-01-28 14:00:00', 'EVENTO REPETIR - DUPLICATE'
'SAL_SALAGRUPO', '2020-01-28 13:30:00', '2020-01-28 14:30:00', 'REPETIR - ANTERIOR BETWEEN'
'SAL_SALAGRUPO', '2020-01-31 11:00:00', '2020-01-31 12:00:00', 'TESTE REPETIDO 2'
```

Há 3 registros na data do dia 28/01, mas 2 deles estão com o mesmo horário e 1 com meia hora de atraso.
Então fiz esta `query` para localizar registros que tenham a mesma sala, dia e horário conflitados:

```
SELECT e.date_start, e.name, ec.sala_c
FROM  fp_events e, fp_events_cstm ec
WHERE  ec.id_c = e.id
AND ( e.date_start, e.date_end, ec.sala_c ) IN
        ( select 
             e.date_start, e.date_end, ec.sala_c 
          from fp_events e, fp_events_cstm ec
          where  ec.id_c = e.id
           and e.date_start between e.date_start and e.date_end
              group by e.date_start, e.date_end, ec.sala_c
        having count(*) > 1 )
        and e.deleted = 0
```

No entanto o resultado é este:

```
# date_start, name, sala_c
'2020-01-28 13:00:00', 'TESTE GRUPO TESTE', 'SAL_SALAGRUPO'
'2020-01-28 13:00:00', 'EVENTO REPETIR - DUPLICATE', 'SAL_SALAGRUPO'
```

Meu `SELECT` não esta considerando o que esta com 30 min de atraso, apesar do dia e a sala serem os mesmos.
Preciso de um jeito que ele considere o conflito do horário envolvido desta mesma data.
Não sei se fui muito claro. Mas a ideia é encontrar conflitos do dia e considerando hora inicial e hora final.

Answer (score 1):

É um problema interessante de matemática intervalar. Uma coisa que você vai precisar é de uma chave primária, um ID único por linha, para que um agendamento não conflite com ele mesmo:

```
mysql> select * from teste;
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+----+
| salac         | date_start          | date_end            | name                       | id |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+----+
| AUD_BARATA    | 2020-01-25 14:00:00 | 2020-01-25 15:00:00 | TESTE AVISO APÓS GRAVAR    |  1 |
| SAL_EVENTOS   | 2020-01-25 15:00:00 | 2020-01-25 16:00:00 | DESCRIÇÃO EVENTO           |  2 |
| SAL_SALAGRUPO | 2020-01-28 13:00:00 | 2020-01-28 14:00:00 | TESTE GRUPO TESTE          |  3 |
| SAL_SALAGRUPO | 2020-01-28 13:00:00 | 2020-01-28 14:00:00 | EVENTO REPETIR - DUPLICATE |  4 |
| SAL_SALAGRUPO | 2020-01-28 13:30:00 | 2020-01-28 14:30:00 | REPETIR - ANTERIOR BETWEEN |  5 |
| SAL_SALAGRUPO | 2020-01-31 11:00:00 | 2020-01-31 12:00:00 | TESTE REPETIDO 2           |  6 |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+----+
```

A seguinte consulta me pareceu funcionar:

```
select * from teste a inner join teste b
      on a.id < b.id and 
         a.date_start < b.date_end and
         a.date_end > b.date_start;
```

Usei a.id < b.id, poderia ser a.id <> b.id, mas aí a consulta listaria os conflitos em duplicata (A conflitando com B e B conflitando com A).

Talvez faltou ainda testar se a.salac = b.salac, não ficou claro na pergunta se compromissos em salas diferentes conflitam ou não.

Em matemática intervalar, para testar se dois intervalos ordenados (A,B) e (C,D) se sobrepõem, o teste é

```
 A < D e B > C
```